# How can i easily gather hardware information for bug report submission?

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, reporting, diagnostic

I think I have found a bug in Ubuntu 10.04 beta, but since its a fairly vague problem of non booting after an install ([Question Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/125950/ubuntu-10-04-install-frozen-at-splash-no-errors)) i wanted to know what information to gather?

*Summary of question: Install of 10.04 goes happily, but boots to a frozen un-responsive splash screen*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you got a running ubuntu system lshw should give a pretty complete overview of all the hardware you have

Comment: I was ideally looking for a magical psychic script that would grab everything, wrap it in a tarball, and file the bugreport for me :D but thanks for the contribution.